# How could you get the real local time in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime, timezone, localtime

I am trying to get the local time but I get the wrong time date all the time:

```
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime

date = str(timezone.localtime(timezone.now()).now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
```

Local region: Europe/Prague

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via "pytz". Once you have it installed, try the below

```
from django.utils.timezone import activate
activate(settings.TIME_ZONE)
```